# Algorithm for query comparison

Tags: databases, data-sets

Lets say I have a global dataset and I run queries over those data set.
For example my dataset would be

- #id, #Name, #Employee, #Birthdate, #number_of_children
- 1, Nick, Nasa, 1982, 1
- 2, Jack, Exon, 1985, 5
- 3, Tom, ABCD, 1978, 0

And I can run queryies on those dataset.
sample queries would be
* #Query => #Result_ids 
* (Name starts with A) => [1]
* (Birthdate before 1983 and have children ) => [1]

I want to store those queries on a data structure and I want to be able to do set operations on those queries like intersection and union. So an example union operation would be.

(Birthdate before 1983) intersection (have children) => (Birthdate before 1983 and have children)

I also want to be able to findout if one query is subset or superset of another one. For example.

(Birthdate before 1983) is superset of (Birthdate before 1980)
(Have 3 children) is subset of (Have more than 1 children)

(Name = Jack and born in 1980) is subset of (Born before 1990)

I will have a program that will have thousands of queries. And it will combine those queries to make more variety of queries. When I have a new query, I will compare it with existing queries to see if I have an exact query in store or have a superset.

Can anybody suggest me a data structure that is fast enough to store and operate on those data?

Comment: If you are using a relational database, you could use something like SQL to form such queries.

Comment: I don't think the answer would be a data structure but a normal form as is used with a calculus, e.g. labmda calculus. Since the queries would reduce to a normal form you could then compare them for duplicates. As for set operations I don't know if you can do those and get back a normal form.

Comment: How expressive is the language? Besides `and`, `or` and comparison predicates, what operations does it allow. Would it, for example, allow you to select people with a prime number of children (a complex predicate)? Would it allow to select people for whom `number of children`*10 > `age` (comparisons involving several columns)?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė I do not need a really expressive language. I haven't thought of a language to express form queries yet. But for now, simple comparisons with single columns would be fine I guess. (I will decide the language after I figured out the limitations of the algorithm I will use.)

Comment: @Paresh Using a relational db will not really help me in this situations. I want to use this as a cache so, There will be a lot of data that will be inserted into the system and invalidated every second. io rate of this would be alot for a relational db.

Comment: @GuyCoder I agree, some thing like this could be my query: {{"<", "age", 32}, {"==", "gender", "male"}} . I could normalize this and check if first and second query is equal to each other. That would be fine. But I want a ds to hold those queries so, I could to this comparison faster than O(n) . And I need to be able to do set operation on them. for example: Q1 + Q2 > Q3. Here I know that I can use Q1+Q2 instead of Q3

Comment: I think you should be deciding the algorithm after you figure out the limitations of the language you need to use. But then of course, there isn't much choice, as this problem would soon become undecidable.

Comment: Here is an idea that I am considering. Some of the parameters of the query seems like a spatial data. For example age , number_of_children, height. So I can use spatial data structures to store some kind of index for my queries. For instance I could use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R*_tree to create an index for spatial structures. But this time, I should find a way to index non-spatial parameters like name.